# User session with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am writing a web app with Backbone.js and require.js that needs to store user information to use throughout the app when the user login. Currently, when the user submits there credentials a web service authenticates the user and returns data about that user. Traditionally I could then store that  information in a  session. How can I accomplish this using Backbone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use HTML5 [SessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for that. Have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/davemo/3875274) SessionStorageAdpater for backbone integration.

Comment: Typically, referencing W3Schools is frowned upon. I'd like to add as an additional reference regarding Session Storage the MDN documentation which is more lengthy and detailed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 0):

Typically one stores authentication information in an encrypted cookie that is sent to the server on each request.  This is essentially a value that correlates the logged in user to the web server's identity store.

You are probably more interested in profile data (i.e. metadata about the user - firstname, birthday, etc).  Once the user has logged in, when the page loads, fetch the profile data about the current user via an ajax call to the server (the request would include the auth cookie, which the web framework would use to find the currently logged in user).  So you should expose a route on your web app that returns a json data structure containing the profile data your app requires about the current user.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently in the process of writing a large Backbone / Marionette application. I'm storing the user information (not password or another like that) in a model called user.  I then use this model to first validate the user by checking the sessionid.

```
// before every request
if (app.Core.models.user.get('sessionid') != "") {
  // then I run the code.  Authentication can still fail on the server.
} else {
  // trigger the event to bring up the sign in page
  app.vent.trigger('App:Core:Login');
}
```

After the user logs into the application, I save the information I received from the authentication inside the `app.Core.models.user` model.  Since my authentication does not return a full user name, I make a separate ajax call to retrieve this information and store that information in the model too.  I then tie the model to a section of my page that automatically updates the user name in the header of the page.

The browser automatically stores an encrypted cookie so I don't have to send any of this information back to the server.